# Formulario para calcular días entre 2 fechas

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy elaborando una tienda virtual en Wordpress con el plugin Woocommerce.

Necesito hacer un formulario donde ingreso 2 fechas y el producto que deseo comprar. Se calculará la cantidad de días que hay entre las 2 fechas y se multiplicará por el precio del producto que he seleccionado (Los productos son los que he agregado con Woocommerce). Ese será el monto que se agregará a mi carrito de compras y que el cliente tendrá que pagar.

¿Alguien sabe si existe un plugin que me facilite hacer eso?

La pasarela de pagos ya la tengo realizada y funciona OK, pero esta es mi principal duda.

Answer (score 0):

¿Podría servirte esta configuración?

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/creating-a-bookable-product/

Dice:

> If the Booking duration is set to be Customer defined with a unit of Days, then another option will be shown to enable the calendar range picker. Enabling this allows your customers to select a start date and an end date for their booking within the calendar itself.